# Is it possible to use if statements with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
<game-tile letter="g" evaluation="correct" reveal=""></game-tile>
```

I'm trying to write a program that guesses the wordle word and inputs it using selenium in python. I want to know if I can write something like an if statement so if evalution='correct' in the HTML code then it does something but if evaluation = 'absent' it would then do something else. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. I would imagine the wordle table is a bunch of rows you could quite easily iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `if` statements with Python Selenium. And, Wordle has already been solved that way: https://dev.to/mintzworld/solving-the-wordle-game-using-python-and-selenium-1aei

Comment: Thanks! and yeah I assumed it's already been done just trying to get more practice with selenium by trying to figure out projects like this.